# Как получить дату в нужном формате?

Tags: python, парсер, дата, datetime, форматирование

Получаю дату в функции:

```
startdate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['startdate'], '%d.%m.%Y')
enddate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['enddate'], '%d.%m.%Y')

print(startdate)
print(enddate)
```

В итоге получаю:

```
2021-04-30 00:00:00
2021-04-28 00:00:00
```

А должен получать:

```
30.04.2021 
28.04.2021
```

В чем проблема и как получить данную дату в нужном формате?

Comment: AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'srtftime'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `datetime.strptime()` парсит строку с датой/временем и возвращает объект типа `datetime.datetime`. При попытке вывести его на печать при помощи функции `print(startdate)` сначала вызывается метод `startdate.__str__()`, который по умолчанию преобразует `datetime.datetime` объект в строку используя формат `'Y%-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`. Поэтому вы получаете вывод в этом формате.

Пример:

```
In [231]: startdate = datetime.strptime('25.05.2021', '%d.%m.%Y')

In [232]: print(startdate)
2021-05-25 00:00:00

In [233]: startdate.__str__()
Out[233]: '2021-05-25 00:00:00'

In [234]: startdate
Out[234]: datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 25, 0, 0)

In [235]: startdate.__repr__()
Out[235]: 'datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 25, 0, 0)'
```

Для того чтобы преобразовать объект `datetime.datetime` в строку нужного формата можно воспользоваться методом `datetime.strftime()`:

```
In [236]: startdate.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
Out[236]: '25.05.2021'
```

или воспользоваться продвинутым форматированием строк (`f-string`):

```
In [240]: f"{startdate:%d.%m.%Y}"
Out[240]: '25.05.2021'
```

или обычным форматированием:

```
In [242]: "{:%d.%m.%Y}".format(startdate)
Out[242]: '25.05.2021'
```

---

**UPD:** метод `qsstats.time_series()`, о котором вы ничего не сказали в вопросе ожидает в качестве входных параметров объекты типа `datetime.datetime`:

```
values = qsstats.time_series(startdate, enddate)
```

Comment: Если я использую     values = qsstats.time_series(f"{startdate:%d.%m.%Y}", f"{enddate:%d.%m.%Y}", interval='days') то возникает ошибка AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'

Comment: @Илья, что такое `qsstats.time_series()` ? Судя по всему функция `qsstats.time_series()`  ожидает в качестве входных параметров объекты типа `datetime.datetime` - зачем вы их преобразовываете в строки??

Comment: Мне необходимо отрисовывать графики на основе данных из бд. Использую данную статью https://m.habr.com/ru/post/126704/. Там используется эта конструкция для нахождения нужный записей дата которых попадает в промежуток от startdate до enddate

Comment: Как обычно в вопросе одно, а на самом деле вопрошающему нужно было совсем что-то другое. Классика.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, это начинает превращаться в "классику" :(